# Why does Eighth have such an oversized head?

Tags: mirai-nikki

All the characters in *Mirai Nikki* follow more or less the same style, with one exception - [Eighth](http://futurediary.wikia.com/wiki/Kamado_Ueshita), who has a strangely oversized head.

> [image: DiaryUsers]
>
> <sub>*Spot the culprit*</sub>

Why is this? Is there a specific reason Eighth has this appearance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wasn't able to find anything that explicitly stated as to why her character design is that way. It is apparent that a lot of the fans do not understand why her design is that way and do not like the way she looks.

I will try to explain my interpretation as to why she might have been created to look that way.

1. **Character Impression**

   During the series, a good number of the diary owners are sociopaths that enjoy killing other people. There are a few exceptions to the trend like [Yuki](http://futurediary.wikia.com/wiki/Yukiteru_Amano), [Keigo](http://futurediary.wikia.com/wiki/Keigo_Kurusu), etc. [Kamado](http://futurediary.wikia.com/wiki/Kamado_Ueshita) is also part of this group not wanting to have anything to do with the game, but her orphan children want her to win and form a little army to protect her. The character design that was chosen shows that she doesn't look threatening in any way and leads most people to believe she is harmless.
2. **Motherly Figure**

   As we all know, Kamado runs an orphanage that caters to quite a few children. This design could imitate how some children perceive their mother. A mother or father is a very big presence in a child's life, and this over inflated head design can reflect how a mothers head may look to a small child when she is bending down talking to a child or infant.

Taking those factors into account, that could lead to an exaggerated character design. Note that this is in no way 100% fact, as it is my general interpretation as to why the artist may do this.

Comment: That's a fairly good interpretation, I like the point on the motherly figure side of things. I'll accept this if nothing comes along with a canon reason.

Comment: @Matt Thanks, Im still trying to search for a hard reason as to why they drew her like that If I find anything else that can shed light on it I'll add it to my answer.